# Laravel + Vue App with barba.js page transitions

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components, pjax

I am building a Laravel app with blade templates which also use Vue components.

What I want for this project are those sexy page transitions like provided by the vue-router. Only that I want to use blade and Vue components in a mix.

I am trying to do this by using barba.js.

Problem is: Whenever the new page is loaded by barba.js (via PJAX) all the markup stays untouched by Vue.

Things I've already tried:

- **Remounting the component (after Barba.js finished the transition)**
- **forceupdating it (after Barba.js finished the transition)**
- **rerendering via v-if (after Barba.js finished the transition)**
- **banging my head against the wall**

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is really appreciated or suggestions on how I can accomplish those transitions.

If you need more information, please let me know.

EDIT:

I think I finally found an interesting package. It is called vue-pjax-adapter. I will try this one out and will report back then. I will also try to provide some code examples for better understanding if my problem persists.

Comment: adding your actual code would help.

Comment: @sebartain Jung did you find any solution to this? i have the exact same problem too..

Comment: @christostsang Not really, i'm sorry. i acutally changed my tech stack to VueJS on the front and NodeJS on the backend which solves these kinds of problems